# Asympotics of Poisson quantile function

Tags: probability, asymptotics

For a discrete variable $X$, the quantile function (or inverse cumulative distribution) is defined as

$$g(p) = \min\{{k \in \mathbb Z} : P(X\ge k) \le p \} \hskip 1cm {0<p<1}$$

I'm looking for asymptotics of $g(p)$ when $X$ follows a Poisson$(\lambda)$ distribution, for fixed $\lambda$ and $p\to 0$.

We have $$ P(X \ge  k) = 1-Q(k ,\lambda )=1- \frac{\Gamma(k,\lambda)}{\Gamma(k)}$$

where $Q(k,\lambda)$ is the regularized incomplete gamma function.
Hence we are interested in the inverse of $Q(k ,\lambda )$ wrt the first parameter (notice that most references, [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1845614/on-the-inverse-of-the-regularized-upper-incomplete-gamma-function) and [numerical evaluations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseGammaRegularized.html) of the inverse are wrt the second parameter, we are not interested in that).

Comment: The most crude idea I could come up with still needs asymptotics for the local inverse of $\frac{\lambda^x}{\Gamma(x+1)}$ that makes sense at infinity, and I'm not really sure how to produce that. Maybe try to use Stirling and then the Lambert W function?

Comment: What have you tried?| Also [casio has an InvPoissonCD function](https://www.manualowl.com/m/Casio/FX-9750GII-SC/Manual/241156?page=242), maybe it can help. The inverse function would be wrt k for $Q(\lfloor k+1\rfloor,\lambda)$ with [Gamma Regularized](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GammaRegularized.html)